# GOOGLE SHEETS: Adding letters to the end of words, replacing specific letters with other letters (Concatenate, Regexreplace, Textjoin?)

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, textjoin, regex-replace

PLEASE REFER TO THE FOLLOWING SHEET:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gz5VHxyn3L2-Y_TQwSrp6LryIvTFxl3N17Da7LSzDaA/edit?usp=sharing

I've used CONCATENATE in column C to add the letter(s) in column B to the end of the word.
Additionally, I want column C to change any of the letters a, o, u to their umlaut form (ä, ö, ü).
In the case of vowels that are together, umlaut only the first vowel (see example in C18: "Häuser").

You may note that M2a words don't add an umlaut.
So, I'm thinking that the formula should reference column D to determine both the word ending and umlauts.

BELOW ARE EXAMPLE OF HOW THE WORDS SHOULD CHANGE:
Uhren   changes to  Uhren
Doge    changes to  Döge
Fluge   changes to  Flüge
Hauser  changes to  Häuser
Blatter changes to  Blätter

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(x,{"a";"o";"u"},y,{"ä";"ö";"ü"}, index(map(A2:A,B2:B,D2:D,lambda(ax,bx,dx,if(dx="",,let(a,join(,{ax,bx}), b,mid(a,sequence(1,len(a)),1), 
 join(,map(b,hstack(,choosecols(b,sequence(columns(b)-1,1,1))),hstack(,choosecols(b,sequence(columns(b)-2,1,3)),),
 lambda(c,d,e,ifs(dx="M2a",c,or(sum(countif(x,{d,e}))=2,countif(x,d)),c,1,xlookup(c,x,y,c)))))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be willing to post a link to the sheet where you wrote the formula? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: recreate the error scenario in your test sheet & I can check it out

Comment: Done. C6 looks right, but the others return an error.

Comment: I set the sheet to "anyone can edit" for now.

Comment: the formula works *array-style*; so you only need to place it in top cell C2 and not drag it down, which is resulting in this specific error!

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to add more designations to the umlaut exclusion list (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7)?

Comment: cant get a clear picture on what you are referring to; do recreate the scenario in your test sheet

Comment: I've added the Ps. They should have no umlauts added. Unless they had them to begin with.

Comment: replace `dx="M2a"` with `regexmatch(dx,"M2a|P1|P2|P3|P4|P5|P6|P7")`

Comment: That works. Thanks again for working that all out. It's now much easier to correctly pluralize German nouns.